# split function does not work in Cloudera Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

I keep getting an AnalysisException that says "split unknown" when I try to use the split function in Cloudera Impala. It seems to be a valid function listed on the built-in functions page. For reference, I'm using Hue to interact with Impala. Does anyone know the cause to this issue?

Comment: Can you put the function that is failing and the exact error? those would be helpful :)

Comment: For example, a query like this: select count(*) from tab1 where length(split(",", col1)) > 0; gives the error AnalysisException: split unknown. Apparently it's a bug in the docs because there's no split function listed in https://github.com/cloudera/impala/blob/master/common/function-registry/impala_functions.py

Comment: it does look like it's a bug.  the error is definitely a "this method is not found", so "split" must not be there.

Comment: I asked the same question in the Google group and I was able to get an official reply. Basically split() is not supported because it would return an array and complex types are not supported yet by Impala...

Comment: Great, you should answer your own question then :)

Comment: Oh yea I forgot you could do that, there ya go...

Answer (score 4):

The following works in Impala:

```
split_part(string source, string delimiter, bigint n)
```

Documentation is here:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html

Comment: Hmm while I appreciate your input, this does not answer the question at all + `split_part` only returns the `n`th element of the split.

Answer (score 3):

I asked the same question in the Google group and I was able to get an official reply. Basically, it's a misprint in the docs. split() is not supported because it would return an array and complex types are not yet supported by Impala.

Answer (score 0):

Split and complex types support has just been come with cdh 5.5 to impala.